# Counterintuitive result in NumberFormat of Intl Package in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, number-formatting, intl

Why does `NumberFormat(".##").format(17.46)` leads to a string of 17.46 and not .46?

How can I achieve the latter, i.e. remove all digits in front of the decimal sign?

Comment: Have you tried changing the property ```maximumIntegerDigits``` of the NumberFormat class to zero before calling ```format```? Either way I agree with you that this is a counterintuitive result.

Comment: @Naslausky maximumIntegerDigits can not be set, although they are in the API Docs. Or at least I have not found a working example yet.

Answer (score 2):

The `NumberFormat` only changes the way that a number is being displayed(basically, what formatting is). So you can't get the fractional part of the number(it doesn't work like pattern matching).
Instead, you can use:

```
var num = 17.46;
var fraction = num.toString().split('.')[1];
```

*Note: you can use `'.' + num.toString().split('.')[1]` to get the fraction part with the starting dot.*

You can read more about the *ICU Formatting* that `NumberFormat` uses in this [link](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/guide-to-the-icu-message-format).

Comment: If it only changes the way the number is displayed I don't see a contradiction to my problem, since it is basically the same as saying: show me maxIntegeDigits=0 which is an actual parameter of the package. The result I am getting here is very misleading in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

‘#’ in the NumberFormat class marks a single digit (omitted if the value is zero). So the number of hashtags after the decimal point denotes how many decimal places you want. For example:

```
double number = 12.1234;
NumberFormat(".#").format(number);     //prints 12.1
NumberFormat(".##").format(number);    //prints 12.12
NumberFormat(".###").format(number);   //prints 12.123
NumberFormat(".####").format(number);  //prints 12.1234
```

You could use substring and indexOf to remove everything before the decimal point, like so:

```
String str = "12.36";
String newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1);
//If you want to include the decimal point, remove the + 1.
```

Comment: How does this answer the question `"Why does NumberFormat(".##").format(17.46) leads to a string of 17.46 and not .46?"` ? If you even use 0 instead of #, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @HBS Your fix works, however it does not explain the behavior of the NumberFormat method.

Comment: @Heikkisorsa Added some examples. Hopefully, it makes sense now.

Comment: @HBS Thanks for the example. However, the behavior is still counterintuitive in my opinion and the API Docs are not correct regarding what properties one can set for the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to the other answer, you can try to remove the integer part before converting to String, and not after:

```
String formatFraction (num a){
  num b = a.floor();
  num c = a-b;
  return NumberFormat(".##").format(c);
}
```

This way you can guarantee it will work despite of locale.

Comment: Be aware that the above code might not do what's expected for negative numbers.  If you want to extract `-0.46` from `-17.46`, use  `a.toInt()` instead of `a.floor()` so that you round toward zero instead of toward negative infinity.

Comment: Also this solution might have problem with precision in rare cases